# Play Framework "NullPointerException occured : null"

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x

I am getting this error, and I understand this error but I don't see why I am getting this error. My model `Course` has many `Session` and `Session` belongs to 1 `Course`. I get this when I try to add session to Course's list of sessions. Here is my code

My Controller method:

```
public static void session(Course course, Integer sessionCapacity){
    Session session = new Session(course, sessionCapacity);
    course.save();
    session.save();
    if(session != null){
        course.sessions.add(session);
        course.save();
    }
    index();
}
```

My View for the form:

```
     #{form @Courses.session(), id:'session'}
            <input type="hidden" name="course" value = ${course} />
            <input type="text" name="sessionCapacity" />

           <input type="submit" value="Add a session" /> 
     #{/form}
```

My Session model:

```
@Entity
public class Session extends Model {
public Integer capacity;

@ManyToOne
Course course;

public Session(Course course, Integer capacity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.course = course;
    this.capacity = capacity;
}
}
```

My Course Model has this relationship:

```
 @OneToMany
public List<Session> sessions;
```

EDIT 1::::
So I found this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/ubGyUOpCHlg)and according to it I am supposed to initialise the List so I updated my Course Model to `public List<Session> sessions = new ArrayList<Session>();` but it still does not work. :(

EDIT 2:::

Here is the stack I get

```
17:05:56,680 DEBUG ~ select course0_.id as id4_1_, course0_.capacity as capacity4_1_,  course0_.courseCode as courseCode4_1_, course0_.courseDescription as courseDe4_4_1_, course0_.courseName as courseName4_1_, course0_.department_id as department6_4_1_, department1_.id as id0_0_, department1_.DepartmentCode as Departme2_0_0_, department1_.DepartmentName as Departme3_0_0_   from Course course0_ left outer join Department department1_ on course0_.department_id=department1_.id  where course0_.id=?
17:06:03,456 ERROR ~ 

@6gbd9kpep
Internal Server Error (500) for request POST /courses/session

Execution exception (In /app/models/Course.java around line 37)
NullPointerException occured : null

play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:237)
at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at models.Course.AddSession(Course.java:37)
at controllers.Courses.session(Courses.java:36)
at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:557)
at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:508)
at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:484)
at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:479)
at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:161)
... 1 more
```

and Line 37 is `this.sessions.add(session);`

EDIT 3:::
Here is my Course class

```
@Entity
public class Course extends Model {
public String courseName;
public String courseCode;

@Lob
public String courseDescription;

@ManyToOne
public Department department;
public Integer capacity;

@OneToMany
public List<Session> sessions = new ArrayList<Session>();

public Course(String courseName, String courseCode, String courseDescription, Department department){
    this.courseName = courseName;
    this.courseCode = courseCode;
    this.courseDescription = courseDescription;
    this.department = department;
}
public void AddSession(Integer capacity){
    Session session = new Session(this, capacity);
    //session.save();
    this.sessions.add(session);
    this.save();
}
public void specifyCapacity(Integer Capacity){
    this.capacity = Capacity;
    this.save();
}
}
```

EDIT 4:::
New error on `this.save` in `public void AddSession(Integer capacity)`

```
17:27:46,017 DEBUG ~ insert into Course_Session (Course_id, sessions_id) values (?, ?)
17:27:46,059 ERROR ~ 

@6gbd9kpf7
Internal Server Error (500) for request POST /courses/session

Execution exception (In /app/models/Course.java around line 40)
IllegalStateException occured : org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an  unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: models.Session

play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: models.Session
at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:237)
at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: models.Session
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1386)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1317)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1323)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:965)
at play.db.jpa.JPABase._save(JPABase.java:41)
at play.db.jpa.GenericModel.save(GenericModel.java:215)
at models.Course.AddSession(Course.java:40)
at controllers.Courses.session(Courses.java:36)
at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:557)
at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:508)
at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:484)
at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:479)
at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:161)
... 1 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing: models.Session
at org.hibernate.engine.ForeignKeys.getEntityIdentifierIfNotUnsaved(ForeignKeys.java:243)
at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.getIdentifier(EntityType.java:456)
at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.nullSafeSet(ManyToOneType.java:121)
at  org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.writeElement(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:815)
at  org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.recreate(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:1203)
at org.hibernate.action.CollectionRecreateAction.execute(CollectionRecreateAction.java:58)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:273)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:265)
at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:188)
at  org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:345)
at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.flush(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:962)
... 10 more
```

Comment: Sigh. What's the stack trace of the exception? And which line of your code does it reference?

Comment: updated my question with the info you asked for

Comment: So, this.sessions is null. Make sure to initialize it. Show us the code of the Course class.

Comment: Then, either your code sets the sessions to null before adding the session, or Play has some "magic" that does that. Your entity should have a no-arg constructor. Add one and see if that solves the problem.

Comment: So I added a no-arg constructor to both the entities and the error has shifted to the next line

Comment: Added info for this new error.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a no arg constructor and initialise your session in this one. If entity is retrieved behind the scene by play it might be initialised using this construtor first making your session null.

Also before saving the course, save your session first as per commented code.

Comment: I still get the error after un-commenting the `session.save();` line.

Comment: Do you get the null pointer error or transient? Have you tried to initialise your collection in the default constructor?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I get a transient error and I did try initialising it in the default constructor with no positive outcome